# Can't figure out why sql query is returning a null object

Tags: php, mysql

This is my Query:

```
$query = "SELECT st.AmountSetElec, st.AmountSetGas, st.StartDate,
                st.EndDate, st.ElecCharge, st.GasCharge
                ec.ElecEnergy,ec.GasEnergy ec.Date , 
                c.ElecCharge, c.GasCharge
FROM energytarget st INNER JOIN
useraccount ua
ON st.CustomerID = ua.id
INNER JOIN
energyconsumption ec
ON ec.User = ua.id
WHERE ec.Date >= 'st.StartDate' AND ec.Date <= 'st.EndDate'";
```

Objective:
My aim here is to return energy consumption for gas and electricity between 01/01/2017 and 01/02/2017. Hence, I have the WHERE statement stating that the records which should be returned are those that have a date between the start date and end date which has been specified in another table.

I know I've made a mistake somewhere, but can't seem to pinpoint it.

Would greatly appreciate some feedback on whats wrong with my query.

Comment: `c.ElecCharge, c.GasCharge` need to be `ec.ElecCharge, ec.GasCharge`

Comment: You should add additional information - the full snippet of code showing the returned object.

Comment: Two missing commas - `... st.GasCharge ec.ElecEnergy ...` and `... ec.GasEnergy ec.Date ...`

Comment: Why don't you just use a between clause?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there can be multiple things wrong -- bad table and column references come to mind.  But the obvious one are the single quotes in the `where`.  Try removing them:

```
WHERE ec.Date >= st.StartDate AND ec.Date <= st.EndDate
```

Comparing a column called `Date` to a string such as `'st.StartDate'` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi, I've removed the single quotes but the problem is still persisting

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT st.AmountSetElec, st.AmountSetGas, st.StartDate,
                st.EndDate, st.ElecCharge, st.GasCharge
                ec.ElecEnergy,ec.GasEnergy, ec.Date , 
                ec.ElecCharge, ec.GasCharge
FROM energytarget st INNER JOIN
useraccount ua
ON st.CustomerID = ua.id
INNER JOIN
energyconsumption ec
ON ec.User = ua.id
WHERE ec.Date >= st.StartDate AND ec.Date <= st.EndDate";
```